# Adobe PDF in Version 1.5 vs 1.7 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, version

i have the following script to get all links of a document and color the first one red.

```
var numLinks=0;
for ( var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++)
{
  var b = this.getPageBox("Crop", p);
  var l = this.getLinks(p, b);
  l[0].borderColor = color.red;
  app.alert("Number of Links on page " + p +" is " + l.length);
}
```

the code works fine on pdf documnts in version 1.5, but doesn't find any links in version 1.7.

any idea?

regards
timm

Comment: All else being equal, if you change the %PDF-1.X from "5" to "7", your javascript breaks?  That sounds remarkably like an adobe bug.  OTOH, I rather doubt that's the situation here.  May we see the PDFs involved?

Comment: PS: by "all things being equal" I mean "open the 1.5 PDF in a binary editor and change the '5' to a '7'".  That way everything else is exactly the same.